# python, loop nesting, functions, if statements

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexoutofrangeexception

This is a somewhat garbled code excerpt.

The context is that it is trying to iterate through a list, building, which should look like [100, 92, 87, etc]. It wants to iterate through each floor of the building and then move that person (by decrementing the current floor) to the next available staircase.

My issue is nesting list and if statements within functions. It's a triple whammy and I'm having trouble understanding the proper syntax for:

- calling on specific parts of lists of lists - i.e. list[i][j]
- using if statements in loops
- nesting loops
- using loop variables in other loops

Here is my code:

```
def Evacuate(building):
    while sum(building) > 0:
        for i in building:
            if building[i] > 0:
                for j in range(STAIRCASE):
                    if staircasenetwork[j[i-1]] < CAPACITY:
                        building[i] -= 1
                        staircase[i-1] += [TRAVELTIME]
```

---

EDIT:

I figured out the issue. Building's input is a list. Staircasenetwork is also a list. The lists look like this

```
building = [100,90,101]
staircasenetwork = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
```

This represents a 3 story building full of people and two empty staircases.

What I did wrong was I was trying to write something along the lines of:

```
for i in building:
    #I'm skipping or simplifying some specific conditionals for the problem here
    for j in staircasenetwork:
        building[i] -= 1
        staircasenetwork[j][i] += 1
```

Which was supposed to take (i) in building (which I expected to be [0, 1, 2]) and (j) in staircasenetwork (which I expected to be [0, 1]) and use those two co-ordinates to iterate through the lists I wrote.

What I forgot was that python iterates through a list by directly assigning those values to (i).

So if I have a list:

```
[100, 90, 101]
```

And I write:

```
for i in list:
    print i
```

It will print:

```
100
90
101
```

Not:

```
0
1
2
```

So the fix to my problem was using range(len(building) instead of building.

This statement takes building and first converts it into an integer equal to the length of the list building using len(). Then it takes that integer and converts it into a list of numbers from 0 to X, using range().

Essentially: [100, 90, 101] >> 3 >> [0, 1, 2]

```
building = [100, 90, 101]
for i in range(len(building)):
    print str(range(len(building))) + " " str(building)
```

Will print:

```
0 100
1 90
2 101
```

So in my first attempt, when i use:

```
for i in building:
    #to call on
    building[i]
```

The first thing it does is it looks at the first value in the building list, which is 100. Then it uses that number to find the 100th number in the building list, which doesn't exist because that list is only 3 values long.

It tries to do this:

```
building = [100, 90, 101]
for i in building
>>> first val of building = 100
    building[100]
    >>> IndexError: list index out of range
    >>> Is looking for the 100th number in a 3-number long list
```

There are ways of using statements like:

```
for i, e in enumerate(building):
```

To create a list of tuples that may look like:

```
[(0, 100), (1, 90), (2, 101)]
```

But I preferred to use the range(len(building)) method. This method may not meet great benchmarks for speed, but it succeeds in teaching me something about how code works and it solves my little problem.

The fixed code will read:

```
for i in range(len(building)):
    for j in range(len(staircasenetwork)):
        building[i] -= 1
        staircasenetwork[j][i] += 1
```

Now (i) and (j) will be the co-ordinates of (via range(len())) rather than direct reflections of the variables.

Lego Stormtrooper has also written a great response to other issues with my code.

Comment: "using if statements in loops" is a very broad area. Can you narrow this down a little?

Comment: Post an example of the data

Comment: If `building` is a list of lists, you problem is in the while loop then for loop

Comment: i'm usually getting an error like "index out of range", and then it points to one of the if statements, so there is no data to post.

how does a while loop/for loop affect a list of lists.

Comment: Can you put in an example of how `building` is structured?

Comment: the building var is expected to be a list [98, 100, 210, 100, 100]

Comment: Well, then `building` isn't a list of lists, its a list of ints.

Comment: will the advice you suggested still apply in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Calling on specific parts of lists of lists - i.e. list[i][j]

You've got this correct in you question, but not in your code. Consider:

```
x = [ 1 , [2,3] ]
```

When we call `x[0]` we get an object, in this case the integer `1`. Not much else to do.
But when we call `x[1]` we get a list (`[2,3]`) and then we can operate on that, like so `x[1][1]` which would give us 3.

In your code, break it down like this:

```
staircasenetwork[j[i-1]]
```

Is equivilent to:

```
x = j[i-1]
staircasenetwork[x]
```

So unless `x` is a valid index, it will fail.

## Using if statements in loops

Use these like you would anywhere else:

```
for i in range(10):
    if i%2 == 1:
        print i
```

Will only print odd numbers below 10. Not much to it.

## Nesting loops

Again, these operate like anywhere else. But you aren't accessing your items correct. In Python `for x in some_list` iterates through the *items* in the list, not the indexes.

So you want something like:

```
    for floor in building:
        if floor > 0:
```

## Using loop variables in other loops

Variables have scope in their block, so:

```
for i in range(3):
    x = i*2
    # i and x in scope
    for j in range(x):
        # i, j, x and y are all in scope
        y = i+j+x
        print y
    # The next line will fail because ONLY y isn't in scope.
    # j is in scope, but is set to the final value of j for the above loop.
    print i+j+x+y
```

## Lastly, miscellaneous issue.

`sum` isn't magic. It won't do what you think there, as `sum` takes an iterable (list) of integers. You are passing an iterable of iterables.

Some of your variables are unset - specifically `STAIRCASE`, `CAPACITY` and `TRAVELTIME`

Comment: Yeah, its a code excerpt, so some of the variables are defined in other parts of the program, however this is a beautiful response. Thank you sincerely!